# why CNI conf file name has number as prefix

Tags: flannel, weave, calico

I am trying to create a CNI conf file.why CNI conf file name has number as prefix? For e.g "10-calico.conf" "10-weave.conf" "10-Flannel.conf". Is there a convetion to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Kubernetes' source code (see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/7297403c69c5605a2728904a84d8216a2db673e5/pkg/kubelet/network/cni/cni.go#L37) and [there](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/7297403c69c5605a2728904a84d8216a2db673e5/pkg/kubelet/network/cni/cni.go#L95)), it does not look like it relies on a specific naming convention.

However, it does process the files in lexicographical order (see [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/7297403c69c5605a2728904a84d8216a2db673e5/pkg/kubelet/network/cni/cni.go#L107)).

I can therefore only guess the convention comes from `systemd` configuration files, and is useful here with Kubernetes if you want to apply several configuration files in a specific order, each configuration file dealing with, for example, one concern or feature.

EDIT: it may be more a question for Kubernetes' maintainers.